# creating a cron-job template for Puppet

Tags: ruby, puppet, eruby

I'm pretty much a novice in speaking Ruby. I'm trying to write a template (.erb) for `Puppet`. My goal is to based on this variable:

```
$c_repo = 'repo1,repo1-condb,repo2,....'
```

to write a template, which in turn shall create a cron-job file like this:

```
43 2 * * * root /etc/zmfs/zmfs-check.sh repo1 >> /var/log/zmfs.log 2>&1
45 2 * * * root /etc/zmfs/zmfs-check.sh repo1-condb >> /var/log/zmfs.log 2>&1
....
```

I can create a fairly simple one with single value though:

```
$c_repo = 'repo1'
43 2 * * * root /etc/zmfs/zmfs-check.sh <%= c_repo %> >> /var/log/zmfs.log 2>&1
```

but just can't figure out how to create the loop for the list. Any help greatly appreciated. Cheers!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
<% c_repo.split(',').each_with_index do |repo, i| -%>
<%= (i*2)%60 %> 2 * * * root /etc/zmfs/zmfs-check.sh <%= repo %> /var/log/zmfs.log 2>&1
<% end -%>
```

Output:

```
0 2 * * * root /etc/zmfs/zmfs-check.sh repo1 /var/log/zmfs.log 2>&1
2 2 * * * root /etc/zmfs/zmfs-check.sh repo1-condb /var/log/zmfs.log 2>&1
4 2 * * * root /etc/zmfs/zmfs-check.sh repo2 /var/log/zmfs.log 2>&1
```

Comment: when I let Puppet to run this template, I get this error: `private method 'split' called for nil:NilClass`. Any idea what might be the problem? Thanks!

Comment: Sure you've read this, but just for posterity here's the Puppet template doc page: http://docs.puppetlabs.com/guides/templating.html

Comment: Added a dash to closing tags (`-%>`) so that undesirable whitespace isn't put into your cron-job.

Comment: Found it: it should should be `<% c_repo.split(',').each_with_index do |repo, i| -%>` i.e. without the `$` sign. But it's adding 2 whitespace at the beginning of the every line. it's taking the "indenting" literally. cheers!!

Comment: Cool, glad it worked for you.  I updated my answer to reflect what actually worked.

Comment: Just a quick question: How can I convert that comma separated list to a space delimited string, so that when the template file is run, I can get something like `for px in repo1 repo1-condb repo2 ...`? Cheers!!

Comment: See:
http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-split
http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-join
For example: s.split(',').join(' ')

Comment: Thanks! worked just fine. I just changed the `split()` bit to be the in the safe-side: `c_repo.split(/\s*,\s*/).join(' ')`. Thanks for the links as well, really very useful for me.